# Android imageview flickering

Tags: android, concurrency, bitmap, imageview, flicker

In my app I have list view and each item in the list contains an Image view. The image is loaded from bitmap using

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

For handling concurrency i am using the method described in the following official documentation.

[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

On high density devices the image view flickers. Any possible solution for this problem?

when i use handle concurrency then only the flickering happens and when i am using asynctask only then there is no flickering

Comment: Try not using WeakReference .

Comment: i am not using weak reference for imageview but i am using it for bitmaoworker async task                                                                                            private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

Answer (score 2):

Use Picasso , Picasso saves you all the problems with downloading, setting and caching images. The whole code needed for a simple example is:

Just use like this (from UI Thread) :

In listview , use this  in getView() , it handles caching and else..

```
 Picasso.with(context)
 .load(url)
 .into(imageView);
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/

or

```
 ImageView tre = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
 String URL = "http://www...sdsdsd ...";
 mChart.setTag(URL);
 new DownloadImage.execute(tre);

   public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void,Bitmap> {

  ImageView imageView = null;

   @Override
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
  this.imageView = imageViews[0];
  return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
  }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
   }


  private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
   Bitmap bmp =null;
    try{
        URL ulrn = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        if (null != bmp)
            return bmp;

        }catch(Exception e){}
    return bmp;
  }
```